# How can flurl be built in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017, flurl

I am trying to build the library, FLURL, found here on github: [Flurl, an HTTP extension library](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl), on my machine with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version. I have selected all of the Xamarin options, all the C# options but none of the C++ options (which shouldn't matter in the slightest, this is a C# library). I have encountered numerous failures of NuGet to update certain libraries, especially those of MS itself. If it would be of assistance, I can post those later but don't want to clutter the question at this point in time.

I need to update the library because I am engaged in an edge condition using the Flurl library with T4 - I'm calling out of a T4 script using Flurl (never mind why, that isn't important). The problem that I am having doing so is that the rest of my library (a significant chunk of code in it's own right) is using Newtonsoft Json v 10. Flurl is restricted to 9.x. Whilst .NET can handle the differences and load the libraries as needed, T4 cannot. It can load only one version at a time and thus I am getting either a not found error when trying to load v10 or a missing method error when attempting to load both via separate paths. T4 requires that one specifically load packages using an internal command and there is no provision for loading multiple versions of the same library.

So...until there is an "official" update that uses the latest and greatest of the MS and Newtonsoft libraries, the idea was to build a local variant, put it in my local NuGet server repository and use that until the official update came out. Only I can't because of the aforementioned errors. So, if anyone can assist in building the flurl library, because they already have and know what the tricks are, I'd appreciate it. My current environment was built specifically to do this (gotta love VMWare) so I have Win 10 creator, VS2017 with all the latest updates.

How can I get flurl to build?

Update: The author has very kindly notified me of an update to the code, however, I am still unable to build same following the (expected) compilation process of simply cloning the source in a .zip, opening the .zip, copying the flurl source tree, opening the flurl .sln file in VS2017 and hitting "rebuild". 
All of the errors are in a single file, PackageTester.Shared.Tester.cs. My VS is complaining bitterly about the lack of a reference to "flurl" itself. And, indeed, the reference list does indeed show that flurl and flurl.http are "missing". I suppose that I could "fix" this by going to NuGet and fetching the latest flurl, however, I am struck by classic "chicken and egg" problem in that I need flurl to compile flurl? As I sit here chuckling, I'm wondering how I should go about fixing this last little problem in order to successfully build flurl and continue using this wonderful library. To avoid any potential sarcasm interpretation, I'm quite serious - I really like flurl and it was painful for me to have to write a workaround to my T4 problem. I got it done but I'd much rather use this excellent library and not have to trouble myself with such things. So...if the author would kindly offer a fix to this last little quirk, I'd be a happy guy!

Updated Update: After having examined the package source and seeing that it was set to api.nuget.org and not "all", I changed the setting, restored the packages and now all is well. The library successfully builds. It would be nice to know how to build flurl without flurl, but that's secondary now as I have a library build that will do the job and, more importantly, uses the same version of Newtonsoft.Json that my library uses and thus my T4 environment problem should now be solved.

Comment: I've removed all comments as they had nothing to do with the question itself.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was not notified of the updated comment until yesterday and not at all about your provided answer (and I gave up checking after two weeks of silence). However, the answer it still no and here's why. I just fetched the flurl source, opened the .sln file in VS2017 and hit rebuild. I am *assuming* (and we all know what that means) that that is all I need do. However,I received 8 errors, all from PackageTester_461. I'll attempt to send the screen shot in here somewhere.

Comment: If you're modifying the source for your own purposes, just get rid of everything under PackageTesters. They exist only for verifying (somewhat manually) that the NuGet packages download and install correctly for various platforms. That's not relevant for what you're doing, so just drop them. (Although, to your point, they should probably be excluded from the solution build in the official repo.)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the tip, I didn't dig into the source to see what it actually does. In my case, I'm not actually trying to modify the source to create a custom version, rather I was trying to solve a problem with T4 wanting to load two versions of Newtonsoft but being able to load only one. With your update - problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some PCL-related quirks that were preventing us from upgrading to 2017 but those have finally been resolved, so the latest version (just pushed today) is a VS2017 solution.